# How to disable NavigationView push and pop animations

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

Given this simple `NavigationView`:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Push Me", destination: Text("PUSHED VIEW"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Did anyone find a way of disabling the `NavigationView` animation when a destination view is pushed/popped into/from the stack?

This has been possible in UIKit since iOS2.0! I think it is not too much to ask from the framework. I tried all sorts of modifiers on all views (i.e., the `NavigationView` container, the destination view, the `NavigationLink`, etc)

These are some of the modifiers I tried:

```swift
.animation(nil)
```

```swift
.transition(.identity)
```

```swift
.transaction { t in t.disablesAnimations = true }
```

```swift
.transaction { t in t.animation = nil }
```

None made a difference. I did not find anything useful in the `EnvironmentValues` either :-(

Am I missing something very obvious, or is the functionality just not there yet?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Xcode 11.3:**

Right now there is no modifier to disable `NavigationView` animations.

You can use your struct `init()` to disable animations, as below:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    init(){
        UINavigationBar.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Push Me", destination: Text("PUSHED VIEW"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `UINavigationBar.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` seems to be the only workaround for Xcode 14 and `NavigationStack`.

Answer (score 20):

[iOS & iPadOS 16.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-16_2-release-notes)

**SwiftUI, New Features**

- Disable animations of NavigationStack push and pop by wrapping path mutation in withTransaction(transaction) { … } where transaction has disablesAnimations set to true. (88993253)

**Earlier iOS**

First you need state for the `NavigationLink` to respond to, then set that state inside a transaction with animations disabled, as follows:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var isActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(isActive: $isActive, destination: {
                    Text("PUSHED VIEW")}) {
                    Text("Push Me")
                }
                Button("Navigate Without Animation") {
                    var transaction = Transaction()
                    transaction.disablesAnimations = true
                    withTransaction(transaction) {
                        isActive = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @joshuakcockrell You are misleading, I tested it on 16.1 and it works

Comment: @gaohomway Cool. This was a reported bug they must have fixed. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: This works for the push animation only - pop animation still happens. If you are manually setting the flag to false somewhere, you can also put that in the transaction block, but if you are relying on the system back button, you are still stuck with the animation.

Answer (score 5):

I recently created an open source project called `swiftui-navigation-stack` (https://github.com/biobeats/swiftui-navigation-stack) that contains the `NavigationStackView`, a view that mimics the navigation behaviours of the standard `NavigationView` adding some useful features. For example, you could use the `NavigationStackView` and disable the transition animations as requested by Kontiki in the question. When you create the `NavigationStackView` just specify `.none` as `transitionType`:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStackView(transitionType: .none) {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                PushView(destination: View2()) {
                    Text("PUSH")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            PopView {
                Text("POP")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`PushView` and `PopView` are two views that allow you push and pop views (similar to the SwiftUI `NavigationLink`). Here is the complete example:

```
import SwiftUI
import NavigationStack

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStackView(transitionType: .none) {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                PushView(destination: View2()) {
                    Text("PUSH")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            PopView {
                Text("POP")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

It would be great if you guys joined me in improving this open source project.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS and iPadOS 16.2, you can disable animations of `NavigationStack`, as indicated in [iOS & iPadOS 16.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-16_2-release-notes).

The following example shows a possible implementation to programmatically disable animations when a `View` is pushed or popped:

```swift
enum Destination {
    case details
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(value: Destination.details) {
                    Text("Push (with animation)")
                }
                Button("Push (no animation)") {
                    var transaction = Transaction()
                    transaction.disablesAnimations = true
                    withTransaction(transaction) {
                        path.append(Destination.details)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                switch destination {
                case .details:
                    DetailsView(path: $path)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DetailsView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath

    var body: some View {
        Button("Pop (no animation)") {
            var transaction = Transaction()
            transaction.disablesAnimations = true
            withTransaction(transaction) {
                path.removeLast()
            }
        }
    }
}
```