# Custom segue animation (navigation animation) in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, swiftui

In SwiftUI we use `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` views to perform navigations (what we used to call `segue` in `UIKit`). The standard segue in UIKit is the `show` segue. In SwiftUI we can simply do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
                    Text("Navigate!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to have the exact same effect (even if the word `segue` has disappeared).

Sometimes (actually rather often) we need to customise the segue animation.

- We can decide not to animate the segue at all, indeed in the
  storyboard we can find the attribute `Animates` (true/false) in the
  attribute inspector by clicking on a segue. This way the destination view controller appears immediately in place of the source view controller.
- Or we can decide to perform a custom animation. Usually this is done by implementing an object that conforms to the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol. All the magic happens in the `animateTransition` method that gives us access to the source view controller and the destination view controller.

For example, a simple cross-fade segue animation could be something like:

```
-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
    UIView* containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    UIViewController* fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController* toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    toVC.view.alpha = 0;
    [containerView addSubview:toVC.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        toVC.view.alpha = 1;
        fromVC.view.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [fromVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
}
```

Now the question: how can I get the same in SwiftUI? Is it possible not to animate a navigation or to customise the navigation animation? I expected to be able to do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
                    Text("Navigate!")
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(nil)
    }
}
```

or something similar to prevent the animation (or to add a custom animation), but nothing changes.

Comment: There are transitions you can use and even combine but I haven't tried them myself.

Comment: I don't think SwiftUI has this built-in yet, but it would be possible to pull it off with some hacking. If I think of something later I'll post an answer

Comment: To disable the navigation animation check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481362/8397245

Comment: @FRIDDAY thanks, very nice workaround, I upvoted your answer. It would be great if we can find a way to customise the transition animation too.

Comment: custom animations exist in SwiftUI as well https://swiftui-lab.com/advanced-transitions/

Comment: Hi @user3441734 I know that custom transitions exist in SwiftUI, but the question here is: how can I customise the NavigationView transitions? How can I apply a custom transition to a NavigationView transition?

Comment: to prevent animation, you can set View.id(:), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602045/list-reload-animation-glitches/60022550#60022550

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately it's still not possible to customise the `NavigationView` transition animations in SwiftUI (xCode 11.3.1).

Looking for a way to do that I ended up creating this open source project called `swiftui-navigation-stack` (https://github.com/biobeats/swiftui-navigation-stack) that contains the `NavigationStackView`, a view that mimics the navigation behaviours of the standard `NavigationView` adding some useful features. For example you can turn off the transition animations or you can customise them with the transition you prefer.

Months ago I asked here above how to turn off transition animations. To do that you can use the `NavigationStackView` this way:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStackView(transitionType: .none) {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                PushView(destination: View2()) {
                    Text("PUSH")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            PopView {
                Text("POP")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you specify `.none` as `transitionType` you can turn off the animations. `PushView` and `PopView` are two views that allow you push and pop views (similar to the SwiftUI `NavigationLink`).

The result is:

[image]

If you, instead, want to customise the transition animation (as I asked in the question here above with the cross-fade example) you can do like this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    let navigationTransition = AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeOut(duration: 2))

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStackView(transitionType: .custom(navigationTransition)) {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                PushView(destination: View2()) {
                    Text("PUSH")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            PopView {
                Text("POP")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For a cross-fase transition I specified:

```
let navigationTransition = AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeOut(duration: 2))
```

a cross fade transition that lasts 2 seconds. Then I passed this transition to the `NavigationStackView`:

```
NavigationStackView(transitionType: .custom(navigationTransition))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for building this framework! Is there a way to navigate outside of the direct view? I am worried that my views will know too much about the app's navigation structure i.e. I would be tightly coupling views together.

Comment: Also, as a bonus point, would be nice if you could speak a bit about how to answer the question directly i.e. how to customize the animations w/out using your framework.

Comment: Hi @Zorayr! About your first question: in order to get what you want you have to change the framework. ATM the navigation stack is created by the NavigationStackView, so you can access it only inside a NavigationStackView. It's not that difficult to change this, though: you can let the NavigationStackView take a NavigationStack as parameter on creation. Then, you can create a NavigationStack wherever you want and inject it in the NavigationStackView. This way, you'll be able to navigate using the NavigationStack (e.g. `navStack.push(MyView())`) outside the NavigationStackView.

Comment: About the second comment: actually, as I said in my answer, there's no way to customise the animation related to a navigation performed with the standard NavigationView/NavigationLink. I'm pretty sure this feature will be introduced soon (maybe during the next WWDC?) but at the moment SwiftUI is still missing this thing.