# How to use NavigationLink to slide new view up from bottom instead of left to right

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In SwiftUI does anyone know if there's a way to use NavigationLink to slide destination view up from the bottom?

Comment: No way for now from the box. Implement custom, using transitions, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446820/12299030

Comment: This might help you as well: [Custom segue animation (navigation animation) in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639845/custom-segue-animation-navigation-animation-in-swiftui)