# Deep programmatic SwiftUI NavigationView navigation

Tags: navigation, swiftui, ios-navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to get a deep nested programmatic navigation stack in order. The following code works as expected when navigation is done by hand (ie: pressing the links). When you press the `Set Nav` button the navigation stack does change - but not as expected - and you end up with a broken stack `[start -> b -> bbb]` with much flipping between views

```
class NavState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var firstLevel: String? = nil
    @Published var secondLevel: String? = nil
    @Published var thirdLevel: String? = nil
}

struct LandingPageView: View {

    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavState

    func resetNav() {
        self.navigationState.firstLevel = "b"
        self.navigationState.secondLevel = "ba"
        self.navigationState.thirdLevel = "bbb"
    }

    var body: some View {

        return NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Place(
                        text: "a",
                        childValues: [ ("aa", [ "aaa"]) ],
                        navigationState: self.navigationState
                    ).navigationBarTitle("a"),
                    tag: "a",
                    selection: self.$navigationState.firstLevel
                ) {
                    Text("a")
                }
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Place(
                        text: "b",
                        childValues: [ ("bb", [ "bbb"]), ("ba", [ "baa", "bbb" ]) ],
                        navigationState: self.navigationState
                    ).navigationBarTitle("b"),
                    tag: "b",
                    selection: self.$navigationState.firstLevel
                ) {
                    Text("b")
                }

                Button(action: self.resetNav) {
                    Text("Set Nav")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Start")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}


struct Place: View {
    var text: String
    var childValues: [ (String, [String]) ]

    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavState

    var body: some View {
        List(childValues, id: \.self.0) { childValue in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: NextPlace(
                    text: childValue.0,
                    childValues: childValue.1,
                    navigationState: self.navigationState
                ).navigationBarTitle(childValue.0),
                tag: childValue.0,
                selection: self.$navigationState.secondLevel
            ) {
                Text(childValue.0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NextPlace: View {
    var text: String
    var childValues: [String]

    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavState

    var body: some View {
        List(childValues, id: \.self) { childValue in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: FinalPlace(
                    text: childValue,
                    navigationState: self.navigationState
                ).navigationBarTitle(childValue),
                tag: childValue,
                selection: self.$navigationState.thirdLevel
            ) {
                Text(childValue)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FinalPlace: View {
    var text: String
    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavState

    var body: some View {
        let concat: String = "\(navigationState.firstLevel)/\(navigationState.secondLevel))/\(navigationState.thirdLevel)/"

        return VStack {
            Text(text)
            Text(concat)
        }
    }
}
```

I originally attempted to tackle navigation transition animations as a problem source - but [How to disable NavigationView push and pop animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305495/how-to-disable-navigationview-push-and-pop-animations) is suggesting that this is not configurable

Are there any sane examples of >1 level programmatic navigation working out there?

Edit: Part of what I am looking to get here is also *initial state* for navigation working correctly - if I come in from an external context with a navigation state I wish to reflect (ie: from a notification with some in-app context to start from, or from a saved-to-disk-encoded-state) then I would expect to be able to load up the top `View` with navigation correctly pointing to the right child view. Essentially - replace the `nil`s in the `NavState` with real values. Qt's QML and ReactRouter can both do this declaratively - SwiftUI should be able to as well.

Comment: The interesting thing about this is that if you use local @State variables in the view this works perfectly... So you could do deep linking by passing along the state via initialization.

Comment: With DefaultNavigationViewStyle that is.

Comment: This may have changed recently  - I put in a feedback report for this to say that if other frameworks can do this - so should SwiftUI. They sent something back recently (13.4.5 beta I think) but I haven't followed up as yet

Comment: That's great news. I look forward to finding out if they fixed this. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

#### Update: Xcode 14 / SwiftUI4

Now we have `NavigationStack` with dynamic heterogenous path support. So updated approach could be as follows.

*Note: although original could be simplified now a lot: a) I wanted preserve view hierarchy b) I wanted to show handling of different model types*

Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

[image: demo]

[Test on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/iOS16/TestNavigationStackDynamicPath.swift)

```
struct LandingPageView2: View {
    class NavState: ObservableObject {
        @Published var path = NavigationPath()
        let level1 = [
            "a" : ["bb", "ba"],
            "b" : ["bb", "ba"]
        ]
        let level2 = [
            "bb" : ["baa", "bbb"],
            "ba" : ["baa", "bbb"]
        ]
    }
    struct Lev1: Hashable {
        var text: String
    }
    struct Lev2: Hashable {
        var text: String
    }
    struct Lev3: Hashable {
        var text: String
    }

    func resetNav() {
        self.navigationState.path.append(Lev1(text: "b"))
        self.navigationState.path.append(Lev2(text: "ba"))
        self.navigationState.path.append(Lev3(text: "bbb"))
    }

    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavState

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationState.path) {
            List {
                NavigationLink("a", value: Lev1(text: "a"))
                NavigationLink("b", value: Lev1(text: "b"))
                Button(action: self.resetNav) {
                    Text("Set Nav")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Lev1.self) {
                Place(text: $0.text, childValues: navigationState.level1[$0.text] ?? [])
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Lev2.self) {
                NextPlace(text: $0.text, childValues: navigationState.level2[$0.text] ?? [])
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Lev3.self) {
                FinalPlace(text: $0.text)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Start")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .environmentObject(navigationState)
    }
    
    // MARK: -
    struct Place: View {
        var text: String
        var childValues: [String]

        var body: some View {
            List(childValues, id: \.self) {
                NavigationLink($0, value: Lev2(text: $0))
            }
            .navigationTitle(text)
        }
    }
    struct NextPlace: View {
        var text: String
        var childValues: [String]

        var body: some View {
            List(childValues, id: \.self) {
                NavigationLink($0, value: Lev3(text: $0))
            }
            .navigationTitle(text)
        }
    }
    struct FinalPlace: View {
        var text: String
        @EnvironmentObject var navigationState: NavState

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text(text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Original

This is because new stack level is formed when animation is completed, and that's why it works in the case of manual tap.

With the following modification it works:

```
func resetNav() {
    self.navigationState.firstLevel = "b"
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.navigationState.secondLevel = "ba"
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.navigationState.thirdLevel = "bbb"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this approach as well - I updated the question a bit to clarify. Doing programmatic navigation with other frameworks allows the initial state to be well defined, so entering the view should not load-then-execute-several-transitions - it should just start straight where the data tells it to be.

I think the problem here is Apple's rigidity on the `Navigation*` struct behaviours

Answer (score 1):

Putting my own solution up here as a option in the case that someone is hitting the same requirements for navigation that `NavigationView` does not seem to be able fulfill. In my book - functionality is a lot harder to fix than graphical elements and animation. Inspired by https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-custom-navigation-view-for-your-applications-7f6effa7dbcf

It works off the idea of a single declarative variable at the root level determines the navigation stack - binding to individual variables seems odd when an operation like jumping from the `a` chain to the `b` chain in my above demo or starting at a particular position is required

I've used the concept of a stringified path like a URI as the variable concept - this could probably be replaced with a more expressive model (like a vector of `enum`s)

Big ol caveats - its very rough, has no animations, doesn't look native at all, uses `AnyView`, you can't have the same node name more than once, only reflects a `StackNavigationViewStyle`, etc - if I make this into something more pretty, sane and generic I'll put that up in Gist.

```
struct NavigationElement {
    var tag: String
    var title: String
    var viewBuilder: () -> AnyView
}

class NavigationState: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    var stackPath: [String] {
        willSet {
            if rectifyRootElement(path: newValue) {
                _stackPath = newValue
                rectifyStack(path: newValue, elements: _stackElements)
            }
        }
    }

    /// Temporary storage for the most current stack path during transition periods
    private var _stackPath: [String] = []

    @Published var stack: [NavigationElement] = []

    var stackElements: [String : NavigationElement] = [:] {
        willSet {
            _stackElements = newValue
            rectifyStack(path: _stackPath, elements: newValue)
        }
    }

    /// Temporary storage for the most current stack elements during transition periods
    private var _stackElements: [String : NavigationElement] = [:]

    init(initialPath: [String] = []) {
        self.stackPath = initialPath
        rectifyRootElement(path: initialPath)
        _stackPath = self.stackPath
    }

    @discardableResult func rectifyRootElement(path: [String]) -> Bool {
        // Rectify root state if set from outside
        if path.first != "" {
            stackPath = [ "" ] + path
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    private func rectifyStack(path: [String], elements: [String : NavigationElement]) {
        var newStack: [NavigationElement] = []
        for tag in path {
            if let elem = elements[tag] {
                newStack.append(elem)
            }
            else {
                print("Path has a tag '\(tag)' which cannot be represented - truncating at last usable element")
                break
            }
        }
        stack = newStack
    }
}

struct NavigationStack<Content: View>: View {
    @ObservedObject var navState: NavigationState
    @State private var trigger: String = "humperdoo"    //HUMPERDOO! Chose something that would not conflict with empty root state - could probably do better with an enum

    init(_ navState: NavigationState, title: String, builder: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.navState = navState
        self.navState.stackElements[""] = NavigationElement(tag: "", title: title, viewBuilder: { AnyView(builder()) })
    }

    var backButton: some View {
        Button(action: { self.navState.stackPath.removeLast() }) {
            Text("Back")
        }
    }

    var navigationHeader: some View {
        HStack {
            ViewBuilder.buildIf( navState.stack.count > 1 ? backButton : nil )
            Spacer()
            ViewBuilder.buildIf( navState.stack.last?.title != nil ? Text(navState.stack.last!.title) : nil )
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(height: 40)
        .background(Color(.systemGray))
    }

    var currentNavElement: some View {
        return navState.stack.last!.viewBuilder()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // This is an effectively invisible element which primarily serves to force refreshes of the tree
            Text(trigger)
            .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            .onReceive(navState.$stack, perform: { stack in
                self.trigger = stack.reduce("") { tag, elem in
                    return tag + "/" + elem.tag
                }
            })
            navigationHeader
            ViewBuilder.buildBlock(
                navState.stack.last != nil
                ? ViewBuilder.buildEither(first: currentNavElement)
                : ViewBuilder.buildEither(second: Text("The navigation stack is empty - this is odd"))
            )
        }
    }
}

struct NavigationDestination<Label: View, Destination: View>: View {

    @ObservedObject var navState: NavigationState
    var tag: String
    var label: () -> Label

    init(_ navState: NavigationState, tag: String, title: String, destination: @escaping () -> Destination, label: @escaping () -> Label) {
        self.navState = navState
        self.tag = tag
        self.label = label
        self.navState.stackElements[tag] = NavigationElement(tag: tag, title: title, viewBuilder: { AnyView(destination()) })
    }

    var body: some View {
        label()
        .onTapGesture {
            self.navState.stackPath.append(self.tag)
        }
    }
}
```

And some basic usage code

```
struct LandingPageView: View {

    @ObservedObject var navState: NavigationState

    var destinationA: some View {
        List {
            NavigationDestination(self.navState, tag: "aa", title: "AA", destination: { Text("AA") }) {
                Text("Go to AA")
            }
            NavigationDestination(self.navState, tag: "ab", title: "AB", destination: { Text("AB") }) {
                Text("Go to AB")
            }
        }
    }

    var destinationB: some View {
        List {
            NavigationDestination(self.navState, tag: "ba", title: "BA", destination: { Text("BA") }) {
                Text("Go to BA")
            }
            Button(action: { self.navState.stackPath = [ "a", "ab" ] }) {
                Text("Jump to AB")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(navState, title: "Start") {
            List {
                NavigationDestination(self.navState, tag: "a", title: "A", destination: { self.destinationA }) {
                    Text("Go to A")
                }
                NavigationDestination(self.navState, tag: "b", title: "B", destination: { self.destinationB }) {
                    Text("Go to B")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to remove the @Published for the succeeding levels.

```
 class NavState: ObservableObject {
  @Published var firstLevel: String? = nil
    var secondLevel: String? = nil
    var thirdLevel: String? = nil
 }
```

This is also telling you how to conditionally change the variables may affect the navigation behaviors.

Comment: Did you try this one? This breaks the touch-based navigation. I think I saw what you were going for there (one `objectWillChange.send()` point) but I still can't get it to not do silly stuff AND allow both navigation types

Comment: Yes, I tried. This solution is directly addressing to the `much flipping` issue. In other words,  you may need multiple viewModels to handle each layer. That way makes more sense.

Comment: can you provide a more concrete example? What I posted above is a simplified version of my actual problem which involves a dynamic number of layers and a dynamic number of elements at each layer - I can't see how to get something like what you suggested working without a genericisable model for navigation at the top level. Also updated the question to reflect that initial state is also important to me

Comment: @E.Coms I tried the solution with the navstate and combined it with the reset nav func from Asperi but I’m seeing the same bounce effect. It works in all scenarios except when I’m 1 level in the stack. The programmatic linking bounces me out to the main view after flickering on the expected view for a half second.