# SwiftUI NavigationView with List programmatic navigation does not work

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to do programmatic navigation in NavigationView, but for some reason I am unable to switch between the views. When switching from the parent view everything works fine - but as soon as I am trying to switch while being in one of the child views I get this strange behaviour (screen is switching back and forth). I tried disabling animations, but this did not help. Strangely enough, if I remove a list together with `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` everything starts to work - but I need a list.

This seems to be somewhat similar to [Deep programmatic SwiftUI NavigationView navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403359/deep-programmatic-swiftui-navigationview-navigation) but I do not have deep nesting and it still does not work.

I am using iOS 14.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var selection: String? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("View A"), tag: "A", selection: self.$selection) { Text("A") }
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("View B"), tag: "B", selection: self.$selection) { Text("B") }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Navigation")
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            Button("Tap to show A") {
                selection = "A"
            }.padding()
            Button("Tap to show B") {
                selection = "B"
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Here is the behaviour i get:

[image: navigationview behaviour]

Answer (score 1):

Navigation View/Link is meant to operate from parent to child directly, if you break that order then you should not use navigate via NavLink.

What you need to do is use a `fullScreenCover` which I think solves your problem nicely. Copy and paste the code to see what I mean.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestNavView: View {
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    @State private var isShowing = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var pMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("View A"), tag: "A", selection: self.$selection) { Text("A") }
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("View B"), tag: "B", selection: self.$selection) { Text("B") }
                    }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowing, content: {
                        CView()
                    })
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("Navigation")
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            Button("Tap to show A") {
                selection = "A"
            }.padding()
            Button("Tap to show B") {
                isShowing = true
                selection = "B"
            }.padding()
            Button("Tap to show C") {
                isShowing = true
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestNavView()
    }
}

struct CView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var pMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Back") {self.pMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }
            Spacer()
        Text("C")
            Spacer()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This does help me to open a new view while being in A or B, but I want to have the NavigationView experience for a user. Furthermore, while not reflected in my question, in my real use-case I have a list presented only on a half of the screen, so `fullScreenCover` does not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting the presented view to take up half the screen, I would recommend using a ZStack to present the view over top of the main window.
You can add your own custom back button to the top left corner (or elsewhere).
This would allow both views to presented and switched between easily.
You can also add a withAnimation() to have the overlayed views to present nicely.