# SwiftUI 4.0: NavigationStack second Subview, movement and back link broken

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm using NavigationStack and struggling with Navigationslinks on second SubView depth.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("I'm a MainView").font(.title2).padding()
                NavigationLink {
                    SubChild1()
                } label: {
                    Text("Goto SubView 1").font(.title3)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SubChild1: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I'm SubView 1").font(.title2)
            .padding()
            NavigationLink {
                SubChild2()
            } label: {
                    Text("Goto SubView 2").font(.title3)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct SubChild2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I'm a SubView 2").font(.title2).padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

When I navigate to Subview 1, animation work. If I navigate then to Subview2 the view appear immediately without animation.
The "Back" link on upper left corner navigates back to the root main view controller instead of subview 1.
Did I miss something or is that a known "feature"?

Comment: NavigationStack isn't a view - did you mean NavigationView?

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce this. MacOS Monterey 12.4 (21F79), Xcode 13.4.1 (13F100), Simulator 13.4.1 (977.2), iOS 15.5 on an iPhone 13 mini.

Comment: @ProgrammerG, did you sleep on WWDC22 or missed it? It is for Xcode 14 / iOS 16 folks... ;)

Comment: @macventure, it looks like a bug, you can file a feedback to Apple. Meanwhile as you decided to use new `NavigationStack`, then try to use new `NavigationLink(_ , value:)` + `.navigationDestination` - new things work better together, at least as far as I tested (see updated part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59404821/12299030).

Comment: @ProgrammerG it is a view. You need to update your macOS and Xcode to run this.

Comment: @ProgrammerG you can't reproduce this as `NavigationStack` is still in **Βeta** released with **iOS 16 wwdc22**.

Comment: Oh ok I didn’t know that. Sorry ‍♂️

Comment: @ProgrammerG sorry for the confusion, with SwiftUI 4.0 I meant Beta iOS16.

Comment: @Asperi I thought the migration from NavigationView to NavigationStack doesn't need change in NavigationLink calls.

Comment: Actually you're right and none of NavigationLink inits has deprecated, and I wrote about a bug, but... you know... :)

Answer (score 1):

So after some testing. If I change to:

```swift
enum Links: Hashable {
    case sub1, sub2, others
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let links = Links.sub1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("I'm a MainView").font(.title2).padding()
                
                NavigationLink(value: Links.sub1) {
                    Text("Goto SubView 1").font(.title3)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Links.self) { link in
                    switch link {
                    case .sub1:
                        SubChild1()
                    case .sub2:
                        SubChild2()
                    default:
                        Text("You reached the end of all Views")
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}



struct SubChild1: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I'm SubView 1").font(.title2)
                .padding()
            NavigationLink(value: Links.sub2) {
                Text("Goto SubView 2").font(.title3)
            }
            .padding(.bottom,20)
            NavigationLink(value: Links.others) {
                Text("End of all Views").font(.title3)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Links.self) { link in
                switch link {
                case .sub1:
                    SubChild1()
                case .sub2:
                    SubChild2()
                default:
                    Text("You reached the end of all views")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct SubChild2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I'm a SubView 2").font(.title2).padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

The navigation works now as expected, but I'have to implement an D.Type eg. Enum with a case for every link.

Using e.g. one case doesn't work and on console I get the message on subview1:

```
A navigationDestination for “NavigationStackDemo.Links” was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used.
```

and instead of subview2 is added subview1 is added as destination.