# SwiftUI: how to remove animation on NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-animation

Is there a way to remove the animation in `NavigationLink` ?

That would be particularly useful when using deep-linking/programmatic-navigation, via the `isActive` binding.

Displaying the animation is that case feels inappropriate.

Comment: [UINavigationBar.setAnimationEnabled(false)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481362/15372665)