# Unexpected transitions when I add and remove screens from NavigationStack’s path at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationstack

I’m using a `NavigationStack` and I’m dealing with the `path` programmatically, so I’m always the one appending and removing entries from it to control navigation.

Any time I add or remove views from the `path`, I get a nice transition that makes sense based on what happened in the `path`. But things start to get interesting when I remove and add views at the same time:

- If after I add and remove views the `path` is larger than before, I get a transition as if I’m navigating forward, which makes a lot of sense.
- If after I add and remove views the `path` is smaller than before, I get a transition as if I’m navigating backwards. This isn’t great because sometimes the user is actually navigating forward to a new screen, but they may have done something that caused all the screens behind to become irrelevant (e.g. after logging in), so sometimes it’s weird to get a backward transition. It would be much better if it understood the cases where the tip of the `path` is a new screen, thus it should be a normal forward transition regardless to what happened to the other screens in the path.
- And finally, if the `path` remains with the same size after I add and remove views from it, then I get no transition at all. Even though the path changes, it’s like the implementation is like “well, it still has the same size, so it must be the same” even though that’s not the case.

Is there anything I can do to have more control over the transitions?

Answer (score 2):

You have little control over the transitions. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72832243/5133585) was about disabling the transitions, and even for that you need to rely on UIKit APIs.

That said, once we know how to disable transitions, we can force a "forward" transition. If you want to replace the top of the stack with `aNewValue`, or if you want to remove the top 2 items, then add `aNewValue`, you can force a forward transition by doing the following steps:

1. append `aNewValue` to the stack
2. disable animations
3. remove the last n things in the path
4. add `aNewValue` back
5. enable animations again

e.g.

```
// this changes the top of the navigation path to "Something Else"
path.append("Something Else")
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1)) {
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    path.removeLast(2)
    path.append("Something Else")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

I can't think of how you would force a "backward" transition with a type erased `NavigationPath`, but if your navigation path is a typed array, you can

1. disable animations
2. insert the new element as the penultimate item in the path (this doesn't exist on `NavigationPath`s unfortunately)
3. enable animations
4. remove the last element from the path

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
path.insert("Something Else", at: path.count - 1)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1)) {
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    path.removeLast()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely seems promising but sometimes after doing something like this, the next navigation transition (and only the very next, it’s fine afterwards) either has no animation or the wrong animation. It’s almost like disabling and enabling animations messes things up somehow. I’ll keep digging to see if I get a better understanding of what’s happening.

Comment: @FredPorciúncula Hmm that's interesting. Are you doing non-value-based navigation, like using `navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)` or `NavigationLink(destination:label:)`? Those things won't get added to the navigation path.

Comment: My navigation path is a typed array and I’m doing `navigationDestination(for:)`.

Comment: It seems like I don’t get the wrong animation after disabling and enabling animations if I wait long enough before disabling them — at least 600ms.